# Key interface never implemented by typescript class

Tags: typescript

Why is this not implemented? I'm trying to make an object with many properties, but all of the same type. However the interface does not work. `Index sigatures of types 'Foo' and 'StringKey' are incompatible.`

```
interface StringKey {
    [key: string]: number;
}

class Foo implements StringKey {
    public Foo1 = 1;
    public Foo2 = 2;
    public Foo3 = 3;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an interface cannot be implemented explicitly by a class. See [this discussion](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398379).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just a bit awkward but will work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using an object:

```
interface StringKey {
    [key: string]: number;
}

var example: StringKey = {
    Foo1: 1,
    Foo2: 2
};
```

If you try to add a property that isn't a number, the compiler will warn you:

```
interface StringKey {
    [key: string]: number;
}

var example: StringKey = {
    Foo1: 1,
    Foo2: 4,
    Foo3: 'string' // ERROR!
};
```

Although, this will stop you accessing `example.blah` directly, because the interface doesn't specify named properties, so you have to use:

```
// x is known to be a number
var x = example["Foo1"];
```

If the type isn't really that dynamic, you may find direct property access preferable because it avoids unchecked typos in the string indexer, but I don't expect this applies in your case - otherwise you wouldn't have asked:

```
var example = {
    Foo1: 1,
    Foo2: 2
};

// x is known to be a number
var x = example.Foo1;
```